# high pincount stackable header separation

Tags: raspberry-pi, header

I recently made myself a custom hat for a Raspberry Pi. To connect the Pi and the Hat there is a 2x20 stackable header. However, I find it extremely difficult to separate them once they are mated together. While I don't do it often, I fear that there is an important mechanical stress that is applied to both connectors and this could break the pi in the long run.

Do you have any technique or tool that could ease up the separation process? Is there something that I also need to consider at the design level? Perhaps you might know about a 2x20 header that is looser from experience?

Comment: It's funny how the friction adds up over 40 pins!  Been there - most of just suffer in silence I imagine.  I don't know of any specified looser connector. There are, however, connector shells that have ejection levers built into them; not sure that would work for you.

Comment: @mike65535 I know that I found male headers that the pins were slimmer on a raspberry pi camera multiplexer. Single jumper weren't even able to mate properly. You sneezed and the wire simply disconnected. If I apply that to 40 pins, then then annoyance might become an asset? But, it's not like you can simply go to Digikey and check the datasheet for that..they are all ''the same''.

Comment: They do make different length pins - maybe that would help?